# Execute a Postgres query in Excel external data that uses a questionmark

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql

I'm trying to execute a Postgres query inside Excel external data tool, using an ODBC Unicode driver, but I need to pass some questionmarks inside the query to make some tests in a `jsonb` column, while Excel doesn't let me to do it treats it as a parameter placeholder. Example query:

```
SELECT jsonb_object('{a, 2}') ? 'a', jsonb_object('{a, 2}') ? 'b'
```

Is there a way for me to escape these questionmarks for them to act as part of the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff in postgres it is an operator to test if a key exists in a json column

Comment: @GordonLinoff: [it is in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html), which, if you ask me, is a rather unfortunate choice.

Comment: See if something as simple as `jsonb_object('{a, 2}')?'a'` defeats the ODBC parameter parsing. If not, you may have to drop down all the way to dynamic SQL, computed columns, putting these queries in their own stored procedures or rewriting them to not use the `?` operator (if that's possible, I don't know enough about Postgres). Escaping `?` straightforwardly in a DB-independent manner seems to be impossible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, I've tried some escapes already, like the one you suggested, also tried  ```~?``` but no cigar. Welp, if there's no workaround to this I can adjust my query to use hstore instead

edit: just found out that hstore key search also uses questionmark...

Comment: How about: `??`, `\?`, `\?|`, `\?&`?

Comment: @Parfait tried the suggestions, none worked... but thanks. At this point i've cast to hstore and now im using ```akeys(column) @> key``` to achieve my goal.

Comment: Wow, what an amazing question...  I wish I knew the answer.